# Can we restrict Restoring deleted files from Recycle bin to the user who deleted the file

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, recycle-bin

I have a classic team site inside our SharePoint online tenant. and we have 2 users (UserA & UserB) with contribute permission. now when userA delete a file, and the file got moved to the recycle bin. then userB can access the Recycle bin and restore the deleted file.

so can we restrict this? so only the user who deleted the file will be able to see and restore the file from Recycle bin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

their is no way to set the permission on the Recycle bin rather it is control by the documents / items permission. Typically user with contribute access on Document library / list can access deleted stuff from Recycle-Bin.  On Side note, Site collection owner/admin can access the recycle bin of the site collection.

If you want to restrict that ability then you have to lower the permissions of that user on the Document library ( less than edit permission).

Comment: Is this still the case? We've just migrated from a SP2013 on premises site to SPO. In the old site users could only ever see what they themselves deleted, but in SPO they can see what others have deleted as well. Is there a way to make SPO work like it used to in SP2013? We don't want users to see what files other users have deleted, not do we want them to be able to recover a file that another user deleted. That is unless the user in question has some sort of Admin access.